# using Gitolite while pull No rc file found error

Tags: gitolite

I am using gitolite as git server. It was working fine earlier . but somehow now if i try to fetch/pull/push its throwing error "no rc file found"

> no rc file found
>   Compilation failed in require at /home/git/bin/gl-auth-command line 43.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/git/bin/gl-auth-command line 43.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

How can i fix this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"no rc" found means gitolite doesn't found your gitolite.rc file anymore.

It looks by default in:

```
"$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite.rc", "/etc/gitolite/gitolite.rc"
```

So checkout your `HOME` (and the actual value of the environment variable `HOME`) or `/etc/gitolite/gitolite.rc` if you did a "root installation".

---

If that file has somehow disappeared, then you need to run the setup again:

```
gl-setup -q /path/to/gitadmin_public_key
```

See [gitolite installation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html) for the various installation method.
See [my own script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh) for an example of a gitolite automatic installation.